# Swift 3 Expect Argument Error

Tags: swift

I am creating some functions in order to make a game similar to Flappy Bird. I am a complete beginner and am trying to understand everything fully as I go before moving on. I have been able to get my obstacle to move but when I attempt to put it into a function to allow me more flexibility later on with multiple obstacles I receive an error.

'Cannot convert type '()' to expected argument type 'SKAction'

class GameScene : SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

```
var Player = SKSpriteNode()
var Ground = SKSpriteNode()
var Roof = SKSpriteNode()
var Background = SKSpriteNode()
let Obstacle1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Fire Barrel 1")

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    // Create Background Color
    backgroundColor = bgColor

    // Set World Gravity
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -4.0)

    // Create Player
    Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player")
    Player.setScale(0.5)
    Player.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2 + 100, y: -Player.frame.height / 2)

    self.addChild(Player)

    // Create Ground
    Ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BGTileBtm")
    Ground.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0.5)
    Ground.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2, y: -self.frame.height / 2)

    self.addChild(Ground)

    // Create Roof
    Roof = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BGTileTop")
    Roof.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1,y: 1)
    Roof.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 - Roof.frame.height)
    Roof.zRotation = CGFloat(M_PI)

    self.addChild(Roof)

    // Set Physics Rules
    Player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Player"), size: Player.size)
    Player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
    Player.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

    Ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ground"), size: Ground.size)
    Ground.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    Ground.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

    // Obstacle
    func addObstacle1(){

        Obstacle1.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: -self.frame.height / 2 + Obstacle1.frame.height)
        Obstacle1.zPosition = 1
        addChild(Obstacle1)
    }

    func moveObstacle1(){

        let distance = CGVector(dx: -self.frame.width, dy: 0)
        let moveDistance = SKAction.move(by: distance, duration: 5)
        run(moveDistance)

    }

    addObstacle1()
    Obstacle1.run(moveObstacle1())


}
```

Comment: If you are a complete beginner please learn first to consider the naming convention that variables and functions / methods start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks for the input, will adjust my variables accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the declaration of `moveObstacle1` to this:

```
func moveObstacle1() -> SKAction{

    let distance = CGVector(dx: -self.frame.width, dy: 0)
    let moveDistance = SKAction.move(by: distance, duration: 5)
    return moveDistance

}
```

EDIT:

Regarding your comment,

`run` is a method. When you call it, it runs the SKAction you passed in. That's it! What you are trying to do is `run(moveObstacle1())`. What does that mean exactly? How can you pass a method call as a parameter? At runtime, the *return value* of `moveObstacle1()` is passed to `run`. In other words, for `run(moveObstacle1())` to compile, `moveObstacle1()` must return a value using the `return` statement. And that value must be of type `SKAction`, since that's the thing you're passing to `run`.

`return` is used to return a value from a `moveObstacle1()`, so that you can call `run(moveObstacle1())`.

`run` is just a regular old method.

Comment: Awesome! That did it. I'd added the SKAction but didn't realise I needed to change run to return. Would you be willing to explain the difference between a return command and a run command in plain english in the context of this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My issue now is getting the node to spawn multiple times. I have tried using a repeat forever action with a delay but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MartinJones then I think you should probably ask a new question. Remember to show what have you tried.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Thanks again, I have up voted you as that's the only way I'm aware I can show gratitude.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
Obstacle1.run()
```

To:

```
Obstacle1.run(SKAction(moveObstacle1()))
```

The error message is pretty clear, you need to pass a `SKAction` to your `SKSpriteNode`.

**Edit**

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene : SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var Player = SKSpriteNode()
    var Ground = SKSpriteNode()
    var Roof = SKSpriteNode()
    var Background = SKSpriteNode()
    let Obstacle1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")

    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        // Create Background Color
        backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        // Set World Gravity
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -4.0)

        // Create Player
        Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player")
        Player.setScale(0.5)
        Player.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2 + 100, y: -Player.frame.height / 2)

        self.addChild(Player)

        // Create Ground
        Ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BGTileBtm")
        Ground.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0.5)
        Ground.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2, y: -self.frame.height / 2)

        self.addChild(Ground)

        // Create Roof
        Roof = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BGTileTop")
        Roof.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1,y: 1)
        Roof.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 - Roof.frame.height)
        Roof.zRotation = CGFloat(M_PI)

        self.addChild(Roof)

        // Set Physics Rules
        Player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Player"), size: Player.size)
        Player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
        Player.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

        Ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ground"), size: Ground.size)
        Ground.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        Ground.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

        sprite.size = CGSize(width:50, height: 50)
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX, y:self.frame.midY);

        self.addChild(sprite)

        Obstacle1.run(SKAction(moveObstacle1()))
    }


    func moveObstacle1(){
        let action = SKAction.moveTo(x: self.frame.size.width * 2, duration: 20)
        sprite.run(action)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. That change eliminates the error message but the obstacle does not move. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: I´m not 100% sure, since I haven't been working with this much, but I created a new `SKSpriteNode`which is moving, check the code. Hope this helps you @MartinJones

Comment: Yes, that did it. The response above also solved it. It appears it just need return instead of run to be used. Thanks very much for your input.